Oracle XML Parse Error specific to non printable character
My XML Query goes like this.
SELECT X.CODE_VAL, X.CODE_DESC
FROM DATA_TBL A, XML_TBL B,
XMLTABLE('/XPATH/CHILDNODE1/CHILDNODE2' PASSING XMLTYPE(XML_TBL.XMLSTRING_TXT) COLUMNS
  CODE_VAL VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'PATH_TO_CODE_VAL', 
  CODE_DESC VARCHAR2(2000) PATH 'PATH_TO_CODE_DESC'
)X
WHERE A.ID=B.ID
AND A.ID='123'
;

This query is throwing me an error for this specific ID and the error message is:
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00217: invalid character 128512 (U+1F600)
Error at line 663
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011.00000 - "XML parsing failed"
*Cause: XML parser returned error while trying to parse the document.
*Action: Check if the document to be parsed is valid.

I tried setting the NLS for my session, converting the output columns into ascii, regexp_replace non printable characters using character classes but everything failed. Could some one please help me fix this issue?
I have around 1.3 million records  in the database and I suspect that there might be couple hundreds of XML data which is very cumbersome to find.
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release - 11.2.0.3.0 - 64 bit

Try converting the string using ASCIISTR first then with regexp_replace and the pattern '\\[A-F0-9]{4}' you should be able to strip these codes out.

Still it throws the same error. I think the XML Parser is erroring out while fetching the data from that specific node even before running the select statement.
